# Place Autocomplete how to do this right

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I'm using the following code:

```
try {
        Intent intent =
                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                    .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    }
```

and

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```

but don't see anything what I want, so I want to ask how to do some kind of listener on my EditText which use PlaceAutocomplete to search for location, it should look like My EditText and under is my map, when I put K it will show all location starting at K under my EditText and I could choose it and marker location with camera smooth move

Answer (score 0):

Well it could be done with

```
  Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                        .zzih(searchString)
                        .build(this);
```

Notice `zzih` method, it allows you to pass searchString to `PlaceAutocomplete`. Also in different versions of google services it can have another name.

The problem is that `PlaceAutocomplete` overlays **entire** screen so you cannot add your `EditText` over it.

When I faced same problem I had to implement UI by my self and use Google Places Web API because some features do not exists in Google Places Android API.

But you can try to use [GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi#getAutocompletePredictions(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter)).

For using `GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions()` you should:

1. Create field in your `Fragment`/`Activity`

   ```
   private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
   ```
2. Instantiate it and manage its lifecycle

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
           .Builder( this )
           .enableAutoManage( this, 0, this )
           .addApi( Places.GEO_DATA_API )
           .addApi( Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API )
           .addConnectionCallbacks( this )
           .addOnConnectionFailedListener( this )
           .build();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      if( mGoogleApiClient != null )
         mGoogleApiClient.connect();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       if( mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() ) {
       mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
   }
       super.onStop();
   }
   ```
3. Create filter, list of available filters is [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3)

   ```
   AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
           .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
           .build();
   ```
4. Set bounds. Notice that first coordinate is southwest, seconds is northeast.

   ```
   LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(39.906374, -105.122337), new LatLng(39.949552, -105.068779));
   ```
5. Search for autocomplete prediction

   ```
   Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, "my street",
           SharedInstances.session().getCity().getBounds(), typeFilter).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<AutocompletePredictionBuffer>() {
       @Override
       public void onResult(@NonNull AutocompletePredictionBuffer buffer) {
           if( buffer == null )
               return;

           if( buffer.getStatus().isSuccess() ) {
               for( AutocompletePrediction prediction : buffer ) {
                   Log.d(TAG,"Prediction placeId "+prediction.getPlaceId());
                   Log.d(TAG,"Prediction Primary Text "+prediction.getPrimaryText(null));
                   Log.d(TAG,"Prediction Secondary Text "+prediction.getSecondaryText(null));
           }

           //Prevent memory leak by releasing buffer
           buffer.release();
       }
   });
   ```
6. Notice that `AutocompletePrediction` does not contain any information about coordinates. So if you need it you have to request Place object by placeId.

   ```
       Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById( mGoogleApiClient, googlePlaceId).setResultCallback( new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
         @Override
         public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
             if( places.getStatus().isSuccess() ) {
                 Place place = places.get( 0 );
             }

          //Release the PlaceBuffer to prevent a memory leak
          places.release();
        }});
   ```

I guess paragraphs 3. and 4. are not necessary so you can pass null instead.

Comment: Could you show me some sample how to use GeoDataApi in code ?